# Fetching data in single file using react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

blogById action.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const fetchBlogsById = (id) => {
 return (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(fetchBlogsRequestById(id))
  axios
  .get(`http://localhost:3001/api/blog/get/${id}`)
  .then(response => {
    const blogs = response.data.data
    dispatch(fetchBlogsByIdSuccess(blogs))
  })
  .catch(err => {
      dispatch(fetchBlogsByIdFailure(err))
  })
 }
};

export const fetchBlogsRequestById = (id) => {
 return {
  type: 'FETCH_BLOG_REQUEST_BY_ID',
  id
  }
 }

 export const fetchBlogsByIdSuccess = blogs => {
  return {
   type: 'FETCH_BLOGS_SUCCESS_BY_ID',
   payload: blogs
   }
 }

 export const fetchBlogsByIdFailure = error => {
  return {
   type: 'FETCH_BLOGS_FAILURE_BY_ID',
   payload: error
  }
 }
```

blog action .js

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const fetchBlogs = () => {
 return (dispatch) => {
 dispatch(fetchBlogsRequest())
 axios
  .get('http://localhost:3001/api/blog/get')
  .then(response => {
    const blogs = response.data.data
    dispatch(fetchBlogsSuccess(blogs))
  })
  .catch(error => {
    dispatch(fetchBlogsFailure(error.message))
  })
 }};

 export const fetchBlogsRequest = () => {
  return {
   type: 'FETCH_BLOGS_REQUEST'
  }
 }

 export const fetchBlogsSuccess = blogs => {
  return {
   type: 'FETCH_BLOGS_SUCCESS',
   payload: blogs
   }
  }

 export const fetchBlogsFailure = error => {
  return {
   type: 'FETCH_BLOGS_FAILURE',
   payload: error
  }
 }
```

blogReducer.js

```
const initialState = {
 loading: false,
 blogs: [],
 error: ''
}

const fetchReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
  case 'FETCH_BLOG_REQUEST_BY_ID':
    return {
      ...state,
      loading: true,
      id: action.id
    }
  case 'FETCH_BLOGS_REQUEST':
    return {
      ...state,
      loading: true
    }
  case 'FETCH_BLOGS_SUCCESS':
    return {
      loading: false,
      blogs: action.payload,
      error: ''
    }
  case 'FETCH_BLOGS_FAILURE':
    return {
      loading: false,
      blogs: [],
      error: action.payload
    }
  default: return state
 }
}

export default fetchReducer
```

blogById reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
 loading: false,
 blogs: [],
 error: ''
}

const fetchByIdReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
  case 'FETCH_BLOG_REQUEST_BY_ID':
    return {
      ...state,
      loading: true,
      id: action.id
    }
  case 'FETCH_BLOGS_SUCCESS_BY_ID':
    return {
      loading: false,
      blogs: action.payload,
      error: ''
    }
  case 'FETCH_BLOGS_FAILURE_BY_ID':
    return {
      loading: false,
      blogs: [],
      error: action.payload
    }
  default: return state
 }
}

export default fetchByIdReducer
```

index.js

```
export { fetchBlogs} from './actions/blog'
export { fetchBlogsById } from './actions/blogById'
```

rootReducer.js

```
import  { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import blogReducer from './reducer/blog'
import blogReducerById from './reducer/blogById'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
 blog: blogReducer,
 blogById:  blogReducerById
});

export default rootReducer
```

Its working fine but I want it in single action and reducer file currently I am using two different files one for fetching all blogs and one for fetching blog with single id. Can I fetch using both in one file when I use it in single file it overlaps while fetching by id it gives all blog and sometimes it works fine. I am new to react-redux. Any help is appricated

Comment: why is there case 'FETCH_BLOG_REQUEST_BY_ID':
    return {
      ...state,
      loading: true,
      id: action.id
    } in your bolgsReducer file ?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal that i have used earlier and commented now